# Output specific text from delimited string

Tags: parsing, networking, text-parsing, mac-address

I have a script that connects to a Cisco switch and pulls the mac address table.  I want to pull out and export only the mac address from the larger output.

Here is an example output:

123    0000.0000.0000    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/1

I want to export only the mac address portion to a file so that I can then import that into another script.  Right now I have to do this manually.

Comment: Do you mean to cut the second field from line like that?
`echo "123 0000.0000.0000 DYNAMIC Gi1/0/1" | cut -f2 -d' '`